# Perform multiple calculations based on multiple columns, grouping by a value within a separate column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to perform an addition based on values in a different column, As well as subtraction from a different column The addition calculation and the subtraction is based on the id value.

**Data**

```
id  date    value   start   status
aa  Q1.22   hello   80  
aa  Q2.22   hi     -200     2000
aa  Q3.22   hey    -400 
aa  Q4.22   sure   -500 
bb  Q3.23   ok      30  
bb  Q4.23   sure    10      100
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    consum  start   status  update update2
aa  Q1.22   20      80      
aa  Q2.22   25     -200     2000    1800
aa  Q3.22   100    -400                    1700
aa  Q4.22   200    -500                    1500
bb  Q3.23   10      30  
bb  Q4.23   600     10      100     110
```

**Logic**

1.The addition will begin at the first display of a single value. For example we see that the number 2000 is a single non consecutive value. The start point of the addition calculation will begin here. Similar to the 100 value (it is an ending value)

2.The second part of the problem is where we begin to subtract the value in the 'consum' column, consecutively for each group.
For example:

we begin with 1800 for the id 'aa' , ***we now want to subtract the next consective value in the 'consum' column***.

```
  from update column)   1800 - 100 (from cumsum column) = 1700

  from update2 column)  1700 - 200 (from cumsum column) = 1500
```

(The first update column will sum the start from status values. (This is now the new starting value)  The second update, update2, then subtracts values in the consum column based on its id)

**Doing**

A SO member helped with a solution, but I have since updated the question and added another column within the problem

```
df['status'] = pd.to_numeric(df['status'], errors='coerce')
status = df.groupby('id')['status'].ffill()
df['update'] = (
        status + df['start'].mask(status.isna()).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
)
```

I am still researching this, I think I need to redirect to the 'consum' column. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You want to create a new column (e.g. `update2`) for the result ?   Should the `update` column be `1800, 1400, 900` instead of `1800, 1700, 1500` given the column `start` values ?

Comment: Hi, the new start value would be 1800 and then the values in the consum column are subtracted from this (based on  the id)

Comment: So you want to update the column `update` in place, right ?

Comment: I have updated. The first update column will sum the start from status values. (This is now the new starting value)  The second update, update2, then subtracts values in the consum column based on its id

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused.  You want to change the logics of how `update` is calculated ?  With the original codes, the values of `update` should be `1800, 1400, 900`   This have to be clarified since we are calculating `update2` based on `update`

Comment: ok- no logic is same. update is calculated by adding start value with status value. Then the 'update2' values are derived off of the new value, 1800. So essentially 2000 becomes 1800. Then 1800 is used in the subtraction of the cumsum values for that id.  ----- 1800 - 100  and 1700 - 200 etc (100 and 200 values are in the cumsum column)

Comment: With the codes above, there will be a value 1400 underneath 1800 on the column `update`.  and also a value `900` underneath 1400, So, I need to know whether the value 1400 will be used for calculation.

Comment: ok no it will not be used. I am working on adjusting the code above to use the cumsum column to perform the subtractions vs subtracting from the start column

Comment: 1700 - 20= 1500 (FALSE) ;-)

Comment: Yes I updated. The value should be 200. I am pulling from the 'cumsum' column @adhg

Comment: Posted a solution.  Take a look and see if it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See working below.

```
s=df.groupby('id')['status'].transform(lambda x: (~x.eq("")).cumsum(), )#Create a grouper
df['update1']=df['status'].replace("", 'NaN').astype(float)+df['start']
df['update2']=df.groupby(['id',s],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['update1'].fillna(-x['consum']).cumsum().shift(-1)).reset_index(drop=True)
df['update2']=np.where(df['update2'].le(0),"", df['update2'])
print(df)







   id   date  consum  start status  update1 update2
0  aa  Q1.22      20     80             NaN     nan
1  aa  Q2.22      25   -200   2000   1800.0  1700.0
2  aa  Q3.22     100   -400             NaN  1500.0
3  aa  Q4.22     200   -500             NaN     nan
4  bb  Q3.23      10     30             NaN     nan
5  bb  Q4.23     600     10    100    110.0     nan
```

Comment: Hi thank you wwnde - I think the previous solution worked? I do not see the status column with the 2000 value in this one? (See post input)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input:

```
   id   date  consum  start  status  update
0  aa  Q1.22      20     80                
1  aa  Q2.22      25   -200  2000.0  1800.0
2  aa  Q3.22     100   -400                
3  aa  Q4.22     200   -500                
4  bb  Q3.23      10     30                
5  bb  Q4.23     600     10   100.0   110.0
```

We can use the codes below:

```
df['update'] = pd.to_numeric(df['update'], errors='coerce')
update = df.groupby('id')['update'].ffill()
df['update2'] = (
        update - df['consum'].mask(update.shift().isna()).groupby(df['id']).shift(-1).cumsum()
)
df = df.fillna('')
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

   id   date  consum  start  status  update update2
0  aa  Q1.22      20     80                        
1  aa  Q2.22      25   -200  2000.0  1800.0  1700.0
2  aa  Q3.22     100   -400                  1500.0
3  aa  Q4.22     200   -500                        
4  bb  Q3.23      10     30                        
5  bb  Q4.23     600     10   100.0   110.0
```

Comment: Let me try this - this appears correct. Will test with my sample

Comment: I would like the 1700 to be offset. Not directly parallel to the 1800 row. I will modify the code. Thank you